# How to increment all numbers in the text that have space at least from one side?

Tags: python, notepad++, text-editing

I want to increment numbers which are written like this:
`add(1 )` or `add( 1)`, but not like this `add(1)`. I have one code that works in Notepad++ with Python Script plugin but it increments all numbers:

```
import re

def calculate(match):
    return '%s' % (str(int(match.group(1)) + 1))

editor.rereplace('(\d+)', calculate)
```

Also, would be very good to know how to increment numbers in only `add(1 )`, only `add( 1)`, only `add(1)` cases.
You can suggest me any software, not particularly Notepad++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the script into:

```
import re
import random
def calculate(match):
    return '%s' % (str(int(match.group(1)) + 1))

editor.rereplace('((?<=add\( )\d+(?=\))|(?<=add\()\d+(?= \)))', calculate)
```

**Regex explanation:**

```
(                   # group 1
    (?<=add\( )     # positive lookbehind, make sure we have "add( " (with a space after parenthesis) before
    \d+             # 1 or more digits
    (?=\))          # positive lookahead, make sure we have a closing parenthesis after
  |               # OR
    (?<=add\()      # positive lookbehind, make sure we have "add(" (without spaces after parenthesis) before
    \d+             # 1 or more digits
    (?= \))         # positive lookahead, make sure we have a space and a closing parenthesis after
)                   # end group 1
```

With an input like:

```
add(1 ) or add( 1), but not like this add(1)
```

it will give:

```
add(2 ) or add( 2), but not like this add(1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Very clear explanation.

Comment: @vasik988: You're welcome, glad it helps.